# How to Backup from mongoDB without locking tables

Tags: mongodb, backup

There is a Replica set (primary, secondary, arbiter) with 300GB data. i want to make daily backup without lock. The Replica is placedWe use Windows 2008R2, so seems not possible to use lvm tools.

If i want to make folder copy on secondary, it needed to shut down mongod first (because its not possible copy mongod.lock while mongod is running).

What is the best solution to make fastest daily backup

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is feasible for you, but you can add another member to replica set. This member would be [hidden](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members), so it would not be used for queries or writing operations. You can stop this server every day for make your database backups.

Answer (score 0):

because it is a replicate cluster i use mongodump with the --oplog option. runs pretty quick on linux. and i think it may have some advantages in a multi tenant server over over tar or snap. disadvange is that the indexes are built when you do the mongorestore